# PHP - concatenate parts in a var or use multiple echo, right way?

Tags: php

I didn't find an answer to this (maybe wrong search), so giving the following simple example:

```
echo '<div><span><a href="'. $varlink .'" rel="nofollow">'. $varname .'</a></span></div>';
```

What would be the right (= faster, better from the perspective of performance or memory usage) way of doing it? Just echoing everything at once or breaking in concatenated parts, like:

```
$thevar = '<div><span><a href="';
$thevar .= $varlink;
$thevar .= '" rel="nofollow">';
$thevar .= $varname;
$thevar .= '</a></span></div>';
echo $thevar;
```

I have seen both ways around, does it make any difference?

Comment: you can also use `,` instead of `.` .   there is no need to thinking about faster execution just priority your code reading and maintain ability first.

Comment: If you don’t need to assemble this content in a variable, but only output it directly - https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, this depends on the situation you have. So, let's consider the cases:

## Concatenation

```
echo '<div><span><a href="'. $varlink .'" rel="nofollow">'. $varname .'</a></span></div>';
```

This does a single calculation and it has no faults by itself. However, if you need to calculate this many times (outputting it in 1000 places, for instance), then you might want to store this into a variable to avoid code duplications and improve performance.

## Concatenation with template

```
echo "<div><span><a href=\"{$varlink}\" rel=\"nofollow\">{$varname}</a></span></div>";
```

or even

```
echo "<div><span><a href='{$varlink}' rel='nofollow'>{$varname}</a></span></div>";
```

Behaves in the same way as above, but you do not have to explicitly concatenate.

## Variable

```
$foo = '<div><span><a href="'. $varlink .'" rel="nofollow">'. $varname .'</a></span></div>';
echo $foo;
```

If you compute this into a variable and then you reuse that variable, then, if you need to get the same value repeatedly, then it's better for your performance to only compute it once and reuse the result. The caveat is that your variable is stored in memory and you need to avoid wasting performance and memory.

## Conclusion

In more general terms, your question is as follows:

**Is it better for performance/memory usage to compute the results of a formula and store it in a variable, or is it to be preferred that you just compute the result and pass it on**

And the answer is:

- if you only use the value once, then storing it into a variable as a minuscule cost in performance and memory usage (assuming that your value is not very big), because storing something takes more memory and time than not storing it, yet, this is such a small cost that you should not worry about it and if your code is more understandable with putting this into a variable, then do so
- if you need to reuse this many times, then it's better to store it into a variable (again, if the value is very big, that requires separate analysis), because computing the same thing again and again is costing you in performance and duplicating code leads to inconsistencies and inconsistencies lead to bugs
- if you need to reuse many huge such values many times, then you need to carefully analyze your current situation

But, everything aside, don't optimize your code before you have performance issues, because the reasons of performance issues are often different from what you perceive them to be. It's good to write high-performing code that does not use much memory, so if you know something to be quicker/smaller beforehand, use that knowledge while you write code, but don't aim for mathematical perfection of performance improvement at the time of the initial implementation of your code, because your effort is unlikely to pay off. It's possible that you will never encounter performance issues with the code you write and if you do, then it will likely be different from the one you believe it to be at some point in the future.

Comment: I see, so var for multiple uses and echo if it's and isolated element. I just don't get the need for my second example, I've seen it a few times, especially in WordPress templates and plugins, even for things that don't have repetition.

Comment: @DanielLemes your second example is breaking up the command into several commands for better readability. I would write it as a single assignment and link the lines with `.` instead of separating them by `;`. But it's also a matter of style, so the person who has written that code has a style that does not make sense in terms of micro optimizations, but makes some sense in terms of code readability. I do not really like that style of code, but that's subjective.